# Access function from another class without having any relations

Tags: c++

I'm still new to C++ and I'm trying to know if it is possible to access a function from another class knowing that no one is the father class here . This is a piece of my program to show you what I want to do exactly .

```
class CSubject
{
  public:
  CSubject() = default;
  CSubject(std::string m_Name){this->Name = m_Name;}
   void print(){ std::cout << Name;}
   ~CSubject(){}
  private:
   std::string Name;
};

class CStudent
{
  public:
  CStudent() = default;
  
   void Method2()
   {
       //Call the print method and print the name "test"
   }
   ~CStudent(){}
  private:
};

int main()
{
    CSubject AE("test");
    CStudent ST;

    ST.Method2();          //Print test;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need an instance of the other object to access it.

Comment: You'll need to pass `AE` to the `Method2()` as parameter: `void Method2(CSubject & subj) { subj.print(); }`. In `main()` it's `ST.Method2(AE);` then.

Comment: What is `unsigned Subj`?

Comment: @Paul An unsigned integer class member variable named `Subj`??

Comment: @PaulSanders doesn't matter I deleted it

Comment: The point of a class is that you can have more than one copy (or *instance*) of that class. So you could have more than one CSubject. The computer needs to know *which* CSubject you want it to print. (In this program there's only one, but you can have lots)

Comment: You can't print a subject unless you have a subject to print. Either pass a subject to the `Method2` method or add a subject to the student class and pass a subject to the student class constructor. Either will work. Which is correct depends on what your program is trying to model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about classes for a second. You want to call `Method2()`, and from there, print information that was put into the `AE`. Suppose you didn't have two classes of your own, but rather, say:

```
void Method2();

int main() {
    const char* AE = "Test";
    // ...
    Method2();
}
```

That wouldn't work, right? And it *shouldn't* work, because local variables in a function (like `main()`) are usable only within that function's body; that's their local scope. For  `Method2()` to use `AE` in any way, you have to let `Method2()` "know" about it. It's the same with classes.

Answer (score -1):

You could use static method and attributes, which can be altered by creating an instance and overwriting it and also getting them from unrelated processes.

I would edit your CSubject class like this:

```
class CSubject {
public:
    CSubject() = default;
    CSubject(std::string m_Name) {
        CSubject::Name = m_Name;
    }
    static void print() {
        if (CSubject::Name.empty()) //checking is a good practice
            std::cout << "The name is empty...\n";
        else
            std::cout << Name;
    }
    ~CSubject() {}

private:
    static std::string Name;
};
```

And you could access the print method from your Method2 like this:

```
void Method2() {
        CSubject::print();
    }
```

But beware! The static attribute is the only one for the class. If you plan on creating multiple CSubject instances and their new names, then you could store the m_Name attribute as non-static private, print() as non-static public, and Method2 should have a parameter where you pass the CSubject (the whole object or just the data that you need) that is in your interest.

Comment: Re: `//checking is a good practice` -- maybe, maybe not. It depends on the requirements of the type being implemented, and there's no information about those requirements.